# Deep nested forms not building correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I've got a controller method that reads like this:

```
def new_edits
  @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  @document.publications.each { |p| p.build_edit(body: p.component.body, name: p.component.name, publication_id: p.id) }
end
```

And a matching form with this structure:

```
<%= form_for(@document.publications, url: url_for(create_edits_document_path)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :edit do |ef| %>
    <%= ef.text_field(:name) %>
    <%= ef.text_area(:body, class: 'editable_area') %>
    <%= ef.hidden_field(:publication_id) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I can only seem to build one instance of the `fields_for` when there should be three. A `Document` has many `Components` through `Publications` (and vice versa), and a `Publication` can have up to one `Edit`. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole approach look wrong to me. Fields for has only one instance because a publication can have only upto one edit. I think you should define it like this.

```
<%= form_for(@document, url: url_for(create_edits_document_path)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :publications do |pub| %>
    <%= pub.fields_for :edit, pub.object.edit do |ef| %>
      <%= ef.text_field(:name) %>
      <%= ef.text_area(:body, class: 'editable_area') %>
      <%= ef.hidden_field(:publication_id) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You might find some issues as the above code is not tested.

Comment: This seems to ignore the relation between `Document` and `Edit`?

Comment: Why though? I want an `:edit` form for each `Publication` in a `Document`.